# Physics.OverlapSphere couldn't detect my ‘Player’

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

This problem happens when the `Player` goes inside and outside of the `Enemy`'s `sightRadius` multiple times.

Here is the bug code.

```cs
bool FoundPlayer()
{
    int numColliders = Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc(transform.position, sightRadius, colliders);
    Debug.Log(numColliders);
    for (int i = 0; i < numColliders; i++)
    {
        var target = colliders[i];
        if (target.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            attackTarget = target.gameObject;
            return true;
        }
    }
    attackTarget = null;
    return false;
}
```

And here are the setting of the `Player` with the `Collider`, `Rigidbody`, `Layer` and `tag`.

[image: Player]

When the `Player` is inside of the `Enemy`'s `sightRadius`, `3` is printed.

[image: Player inside]

When the `Player` is outside of the `Enemy`'s `sightRadius`, `2` is printed.

[image: Player outside]

After I control the `Player` to go inside and outside of the `sightRadius` several times, when the `Player` is inside of the `sightRadius`, `2`
instead of `3` is printed, and the `Enemy` doesn't chase the `Player` anymore. If I restart the game, it works well again.

[image: Player inside wrong]

This problem happens both in `Unity` 2020 and 2022.

My code used `OverlapSphereNonAlloc`, but I met the same problem, trying to use both `OverlapSphereNonAlloc` and `OverlapSphere`.

Here is the full code of the `Enemy`.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;


enum EnemyStatus 
{   
    GURAD, 
    PATROL, 
    CHASE, DEAD 
}

[RequireComponent(typeof(NavMeshAgent))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(BoxCollider))]
public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private EnemyStatus enemyStates;
    private NavMeshAgent agent;
    private Animator animator;

    [Header("Basic Settings")]
    public float sightRadius;
    private GameObject attackTarget;
    // enermy will find 10 max players at one frame 
    const int maxColliders = 10;
    private Collider[] colliders = new Collider[maxColliders];

    // speed set in agent.speed, but patrol, chase and return from chase have different speed
    private float speed;
    // is GUARD or PATROL when no enemy
    public bool isGuard;


    [Header("Patrol State")]
    public float patrolRange;
    private Vector3 wayPoint;
    private Vector3 centerPosition;

    // animator
    bool isWalk;

    // entry of Chase Layer
    bool isChase;
    // 
    bool isFollow;

    private void Awake()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        animator =  GetComponent<Animator>();
        speed = agent.speed;
        wayPoint = centerPosition = transform.position;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        if (isGuard)
        {
            enemyStates = EnemyStatus.GURAD;
        } 
        else
        {
            enemyStates = EnemyStatus.PATROL;
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        SwitchStates();
        SwitchAnimation();
    }

    void SwitchAnimation()
    {
        animator.SetBool("Walk", isWalk);
        animator.SetBool("ChaseState", isChase);
        animator.SetBool("Follow", isFollow);
    }

    private void SwitchStates()
    {
        if (FoundPlayer())
        {
            enemyStates = EnemyStatus.CHASE;
        }
        switch(enemyStates)
        {
            case EnemyStatus.GURAD:
                break;
            case EnemyStatus.PATROL:
                // this is error, when enemy reach wayPoint, it will stop walking
                // isWalk = true;
                isChase = false;
                isFollow = false;

                if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position, wayPoint) <= agent.stoppingDistance )
                {
                    wayPoint = GetNewWayPoint();
                    agent.destination = wayPoint;
                    agent.speed = speed * 0.5f;
                    isWalk = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    isWalk = true;
                }
                break;
            case EnemyStatus.CHASE:

                //TODO: back to gurad or patrol if player far away
                //TODO: attack player
                //TODO: attack animator
                isWalk = false;
                isChase = true;
                if (FoundPlayer())
                {
                    //TODO: chase player
                    agent.destination = attackTarget.transform.position;
                    agent.speed = speed;
                    isFollow = true;
                } 
                else
                {
                    isFollow = false;
                    // stop at the current when lost target
                    agent.destination = transform.position;
                }
                break;
            case EnemyStatus.DEAD:
                break;
        }
    }

    bool FoundPlayer()
    {
        int numColliders = Physics.OverlapSphereNonAlloc(transform.position, sightRadius, colliders);
        Debug.Log(numColliders);
        for (int i = 0; i < numColliders; i++)
        {
            var target = colliders[i];
            if (target.CompareTag("Player"))
            {
                attackTarget = target.gameObject;
                return true;
            }
        }
        attackTarget = null;
        return false;
    }

    Vector3 GetNewWayPoint ()
    {
        Vector3 wayPoint = new Vector3(centerPosition.x + Random.Range(-patrolRange, patrolRange), centerPosition.y, centerPosition.z + Random.Range(-patrolRange, patrolRange));
        NavMeshHit hit;
        // sample the nearnet reachable point for enemy to go.
        // if can not find any point, SamplePosition will retturn false and enemy will stand there for next sample next frame.
        wayPoint = NavMesh.SamplePosition(wayPoint, out hit, patrolRange, 1) ? hit.position : transform.position;
        return wayPoint;
    }
    private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.blue;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(transform.position, sightRadius);
        Vector3 size = new Vector3(patrolRange, patrolRange, patrolRange);
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(centerPosition, size);
    }
}
```

I have tried a different `API` and a different version of `Unity`.

I found out that enabling the `Use gravity` on the `Rigidbody` component causes this problem, but I don't know how it happens. The `Player` stands on the plane and the `transform.position`, but the position in the info of the `Rigidbody` component keeps decreasing.

[image: Rigidbody]

Here is the configuration of `Plane`.

[image: Plane]

Comment: while youve put a lot of information, id not say this is a [mcve] you havent shown settings on the player, nor where the magic numbers are coming from,